# How Random email generation and capturing work

Tags: email, random, spamassassin

I would like to understand how can I capture emails sent to different random email ids generated by server in one inbox to run analysis on those emails something like this website does : https://www.mail-tester.com/

Here , with each page referesh, you would notice a new random email id is generated. If an email is sent to this random email id, the mail-tester server captures that email, assesses it using spamassassin and generates a report. I want to understand how can we capture emails sent to so many different random email ids in a single inbox so that they can be assessed by spamassassin or any other utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practial implementation for unix/linux sendmail using procmail as its local mailer.

1. Use `FEATURE(virtusertable)` to redirect messages for `xyz@test.example.net` to `user+xyz` (user `user` with `+xyz` "detail").
2. `~user/.procmailrc` will process incoming messages upon delivery.  `xyz` (+detail) will be available via `$1`.

See also: [Sendmail-FAQ-3.29: How can I add a header specifying the actual recipient when having multiple users in a virtual domain go to a single mailbox](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/faq_ver_8_issues/#3.29)?

Comment: Thanks Andrzej, I will try it out .